# Capturing a TextView value within a TableViewCell, when a button in another TableViewCell is pressed before segueing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have the following tableView:

[image]

When the user clicks the blue Pay Cash/Card button, they segue to another tableView.

The problem I have is; when the user clicks the button, the value of the textView doesn't get captured within the delegate method. For example, I have implemented the 'TextView' protocol and implemented the following functions from the TextView class:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Enter a note for the takeaway (optional)"
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    } else {
        self.note = textView.text
    }
}
```

As you can see, if I enter some text, and then click the Done button, before clicking the segue button, I'm able to pass the value successfully. However, if the user clicks the blue segue button before clicking done, it segues and I'm unsure how to capture the value of the textView. The code for my button delegate is below, and I've also passed my prepareForSegue method.

I hope what I'm trying to achieve makes sense; I do struggle explaining things, so please let me know if I'm unclear and I'll try expand further.

Thanks,
J

```
func buttonPressed() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNameAddress", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "showNameAddress") {
        let nameAddressTableViewController = segue.destination as! NameAddressTableViewController
        if(self.delivery == true) {
            nameAddressTableViewController.delivery = true
            nameAddressTableViewController.finalPrice = self.basket.totalPriceOfAllItems() + Double(BasketArrays.deliveryCharge)!
        } else {
            nameAddressTableViewController.delivery = false
            nameAddressTableViewController.finalPrice = self.basket.totalPriceOfAllItems()
        }
        nameAddressTableViewController.note = self.note
        nameAddressTableViewController.show(self, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the value of the string in `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool`.

I haven't tested this code but it would look something like:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, 
replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    self.note = textView.text + text
    return true
}
```

That way your `self.note` variable is always up to date with the changes on each keypress.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks so much. I'll mark your answer once the 3 minutes are up. All the best!